# Imported blogs not showing up under proper tab

Tags: views, organic-groups, feeds, 7, nodes

In using Acquia/Drupal Commons and the Feeds module, we have successfully pulled in a few WordPress feeds. While the Organic Group is assigned and the newly created feeds appear in the OG's Home tab, they do not show up under the blog tag until I visit each one, click the edit tab, and then click save.

Given that, I assume I haven't mapped something that the `group_tab_blogs` View is searching on.

Additionally, if I copy the Query produced from `group_tab_blogs` live preview, copy it into a mysql client, and run, the results **do** show up. So that leads me to believe that it's something in the view filters.

Current Mapping between Source (Feed node) and Target (Blog node):
 [image: Current Mapping between Source (Feed node) and Target (Blog node)]

Current `group_tab_blogs` settings:
 [image: Current <code>group_tab_blogs</code> settings]

**Update:**

I can fix this by a manual running the query below. Once we set the field `field_group_sticky_value` of from table `content_field_group_sticky` to 'Not Sticky' it is now showing up.

```
 update content_field_group_sticky set field_group_sticky_value='Not Sticky';
```

However, I can't just map target fields Sticky and Group Sticky to just any value. I've already tried Published Date. So now I either need to run the above query on a trigger or adjust the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that query list above was the key. So I just threw it into a module cron. When feeds are imported on each cron run, this query runs and corrects the null value in the table.

```
function hook_cron() {
      db_query("update content_field_group_sticky set field_group_sticky_value='Not Sticky' where field_group_sticky_value is null");
}
```